# how to restrict request when entity in requests is too large in node js?

Tags: node.js, sails.js, http-status-code-413

I am using sails js version 1.2.4 and node version 12.16.1.

I am suddenly getting http 413 error code that is Request entity too large in error logs of my server and i am sure that i have not sent those request. I know that a 413 HTTP error code occurs when the size of a client’s request exceeds the server’s file size limit. This typically happens when a client attempts to upload a large file to a web server.

I want to restrict it for security reasons. I dont want to increase the server allowed limit size or anything about increasing the config.

I want to return the 200 response with message saying "Request size is not allowed" for request where entity is too large.

I have went through many blogs and stackoverflow questions, but everybody is talking about increasing the allowed size on server But I do not want to do that for security reasons.

Can anyone help me?